# How to use onchange with many2one in odoo(formally openerp)

Tags: python, odoo, erp

1.I have two fields like "employee name" and "department".If i change the employee name in the first field,then the second filed("department") should be auto populate.please provide .py and .xml
Thanx in advance

Comment: SO is not the place to solve assignments and give ready-made answers.Kindly put in some effort and mention where you need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for reference :

**.py**

```
class HR(models.Model):
    _name = 'hr.hr'

    employee = fields.Many2one('emp.emp', string="Employee")
    department = fields.Many2one('emp.dept',related='employee.department',string="Department") 
    #related attribute will automatically change as you change employee and fill the department field


# Master of Employee
class Employee(models.Model):

    _name = 'emp.emp'

    name = fields.Char('Employee Name')
    department = fields.Many2one('emp.dept',string="Department")

# Master of Department
class Department(models.Model):

    _name = 'emp.dept'

    name = fields.Char('Department Name')
```

**.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="employee_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.hr.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.hr</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="HR">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="employee"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="department"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

<!-- Write Tree View, Action, and Menu Code on your own -->
<!-- Also create view xml file for Employee Master and Department Master to enter Data -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Its's working.I have wasted 2 days of time using onchange.

Comment: I think you are beginner.